# 独｛ひと｝り善｛よ｝がりの考え - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm struggling to understand this [definition](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/186406/meaning/m0u/):

> ［名・形動］他人の意見を無視して、自分だけでよいと思い込んでいること。また、そのさま。どくぜん。「―な（の）言動」. 「デジタル大辞泉」

Namely this part:

> 自分だけでよいと思い込んでいる

I am not sure what "thinking that only yourself is good" (can't find a less awkward literal way to translate) would mean in Japanese.

Arrogant? (e.g. giving advice in a patronizing manner)

Or acts only out of self interest? (e.g. not giving advice thinking it would be a waste of time but being humble about it)

Or - only values his own opinion (short-sighted, myopic - disregarding any opinions that may be contrary to his own).

Could someone please help me clarify how someone would use 独り善がりの考え to describe someone?

お助けください

Comment: I'm deleting my answer. It might be easier for someone to answer if you (a) explain what motivates the question [did you get an e-mail that has this word in it? are you reading a novel that contains it? are you just mining the dictionary for something you want to write yourself?] and (b) indicated the nuances you think a particular **set** of words has rather than just this one ... Separately, you can consult a corpus for Japanese if you want to see how it is used: http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/

Comment: Based on the corpus, I would say the closest translation would be either solipsistic or narcissistic. I would also it doesn't look like a very common word...

Comment: The motivation is as basic as can be, I think. Word meaning. E.g. if I were to ask an English native speaker what 'arrogant' means and how it's used, I think he'd just explain it there and then. *If* he had the appropriate command of his own language, that is.

Comment: To further clarify - one of my hardest to overcome language-learning barriers in the past has been sticking to wrong word meanings that are very hard to re-learn once they "stick". Therefore, when in doubt, I think it's justifiable to search for the correct meaning right away instead of hoping to be right and then spending a lot of time trying to  "re-write" your own memory if it turns out to be wrong.

Comment: "Word meaning" is not really a motivation. I at least encounter several thousand Japanese words each day, but I don't bother asking each as a question here. What specifically motivates wanting to know what this word means, i.e.,  **where** you saw this word.

Comment: @virmaior It is a very common word.

Comment: @cirno You cannot say 「お助けてください」.　「お助け」 is a noun, not a verb, so you cannot throw in a 「て」.

Answer (score 3):

> "I am not sure what "***thinking that only yourself is good***" (can't find a less awkward literal way to translate) would mean in Japanese."

But that is not what the definition says.  It says:

> 「自分だけ**で**よいと思い込んでいる」

It does not say:

> 「自分だけ**が**よいと思い込んでいる」

「自分だけ**で**」 means "**only among oneself**" literally.  ⇒ "You falsely believe something is good (without listening to others' opinions)."

> "Arrogant?"

No, that is what 「自分だけ**が**よいと思い込んでいる」 roughly means.

> "Or acts only out of self interest? (e.g. not giving advice thinking it would be a waste of time but being humble about it)"

Getting kinda closer but not very much.  You still clearly have "arrogant" in your head.  A「独りよがりな人」 is not open to others' advice.  It is not that s/he does not give advice to others.  In fact, s/he will probably give lots of **biased** advice to others.

> "Or - only values his own opinion (short-sighted, myopic - disregarding any opinions that may be contrary to his own)."

Finally! I had been wanting to hear that!

**If you are a self-satisfied and complacent kind of person, you would be called 「独りよがりな人」 and your ideas would be called 「独りよがりな考え」.**

EDIT: It might help to think of 「よがり」 as the noun form of the verb 「よがる」, which means "to consider good", "to feel satisfied", etc.  「独りよがり」 is doing that all by yourself without consulting others.

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%96%84%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E8%89%AF%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B-405290#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

Comment: self-satisfied or myopic sounds correct, but i'm not sure it can mean "complacent" -- the definition provided by the OP says "ignoring the opinions/views of others" -- just a tiny detail though

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/ejword/complacent

Comment: because japanese dictionaries are never incorrect when using english words ;D